# Problems with installting cURL on Nginx + php 7 (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: software-installation, php, nginx, curl, php7

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt_array()
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, with nginx + php 7.

I have tried following all of the tutorials I've stumbled upon in stackoverflow (askubuntu, serverfault)

What I have done so far:

```
$ sudo apt-get update   
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done   
php7.0-curl is already the newest version.   


$ php -m | grep curl   

PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0   
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Looking in phpinfo (not in console, in web) I get the paths:

```
Loaded Configuration File:  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini   
Additional .ini files parsed: ....  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini ....
```

In that `php.ini` I have commented out the line:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Also:

```
$ ls conf.d/ | grep curl
20-curl.ini
```

Then I restarted nginx using:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

and restarted php7 using:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Still not working... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting the error on your terminal or from your browser?

Comment: in the Browser, see. Looking in phpinfo (not in console, in web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of work I managed to solve the problem with an upgrade. Then it started to work!

The secret was:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I configure nginx+php+mysql+phpmyadmin in Ubuntu. Follow the steps below.

1. Get Ready. Open the terminal and update Ubuntu.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install and start Nginx.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nginx
   ```
3. Check whether it is installed. Visit `http://localhostr`. If you see “Welcome to Nginx！”, it means it has been installed.
4. Install mysql (You will be asked to set a password for the default account which is root).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-clinet
   ```
5. Install phpmyadmin and create a soft link in root directory of virtual machine.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin sudo In -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/****.com/
   ```

   Stars can be the domain name of your website for convenience. /var/www/****.com/ is the address of the virtual machine.
6. Install php and extensions.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cgi php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-ming php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-sqlite php5-xsl
   ```
7. Install spawn-fcgi (for php5 cgi).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install spawn-fcgi
   ```
8. In Nginx, congifure spawn-fcgi (use nano to locate the file and change it.)

   - Add `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` to `在/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`

     ```
     sudo sed -i '$ i fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;' /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
     ```
9. Modify php.ini and set cgi.fix_pathinfo as 1.

   ```
   sudo sed -i '/cgi.fix_pathinfo=/ c cgi.fix_pathinfo=1;' /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
   ```
10. Start fastcgi and set boot startup.

    - `sudo /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -C 5 -u www-data -g www-data -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi -P /var/run/fastcgi-php.pid`
    - Set boot startup, which is to add `/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -C
      5 -u www-data -g www-data -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi -P 
      /var/run/fastcgi-php.pid` to `/etc/rc.local`
    - `sudo sed -i '/^exit/ i /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -C 5 
      -u www-data -g www-data -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi -P 
      /var/run/fastcgi-php.pid' /etc/rc.local`
11. Configure virtual machine in Nginx (VERY IMPORTANT).

    - `sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/****.com` Stars can be any name you want.
    - Modify site ****.com .conf and add

      ```
      server {   
      listen 80; #WordPress access port (Default 80)   
      server_name ***.com www.***.com; #hostname，bind domain  
      root /var/www/***.com; #root directory of site    
      location / {   
      index index.php;  
      }   
      location ~ \.php$ {   
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;   
      fastcgi_index index.php;   
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;  
      }  
      }
      ```
12. Start Nginx / php

    ```
    sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart  
    /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -C 5 /usr/bin/php-cgi
    ```

After it is done, access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` via `http://localhost`.